# CSS Flexbox - Center a div between two divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a logo between a nav and a search button and I want to center the logo in the page. Using a horizontal auto margin makes the center div go to the right as the content on the left is larger.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left-nav">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <a href="#">Link4</a>
    <a href="#">Link5</a>
    <a href="#">Link6</a>
    <a href="#">Link7</a>
    <a href="#">Link8</a>

  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="right-search">
    search
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your css.

It makes the divs a certain width on the monitor, and centers the logo text.

```css
    .flexbox {
      display: flex;
    }
    .left-nav{
     width:25%;
    }
    .logo {
      width:50%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .right-search{
     width:25%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left-nav">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <a href="#">Link4</a>
    <a href="#">Link5</a>
    <a href="#">Link6</a>
    <a href="#">Link7</a>
    <a href="#">Link8</a>

  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="right-search">
    search
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.left-nav,
.right-search {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.logo {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And don't forget to add vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flex-basis value & then set the shrink value on these elements, so they can have a respective width based on its basis.
You also need to declare `align-items: center`

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flexbox>div {
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

.left-nav {
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-shrink: 2;
}

.logo {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-search {
  flex-shrink: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left-nav">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <a href="#">Link4</a>
    <a href="#">Link5</a>
    <a href="#">Link6</a>
    <a href="#">Link7</a>
    <a href="#">Link8</a>

  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="right-search">
    search
  </div>
</div>
```